# NFSv4 not able to set any sockets for nfsd without running rpcbind

Tags: redhat, nfs, nfs4, rpc

According to [Red Hat docs](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-nfs.html) 'rpcbind' is not required any more:

> Because protocol support has been incorporated into the v4 protocol,
>   NFSv4 has no interaction with the portmap, rpc.lockd, and rpc.statd
>   daemons. NFSv4 listens on the well-known TCP port 2049, which
>   eliminates the need for portmap interaction. The mounting and locking
>   protocols have been incorporated into the V4 protocol which eliminates
>   the need for interaction with rpc.lockd and rpc.statd. The rpc.mountd
>   daemon is still required on the server, but is not involved in any
>   over-the-wire operations.

however I'm not able to start NFS demon when 'rpcbind' service is not running:

```
# service nfs start
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas: Cannot register service: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
rpc.rquotad: unable to register (RQUOTAPROG, RQUOTAVERS, udp).
                                                           [FAILED]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon: rpc.nfsd: writing fd to kernel failed: errno 111 (Connection refused)
rpc.nfsd: unable to set any sockets for nfsd
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I've disabled NFS v2 and v3:

```
# grep -v "^#" /etc/sysconfig/nfs
MOUNTD_NFS_V2="no"
MOUNTD_NFS_V3="no"
RPCNFSDARGS="-N 2 -N 3"
```

Could you please confirm what services are required/essential on server and client from these listed below (basically I would like to disable services which are not needed):

```
# rpm -ql nfs-utils | grep 'init.d'
/etc/rc.d/init.d/nfs
/etc/rc.d/init.d/nfslock
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rpcgssd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rpcidmapd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rpcsvcgssd
```

Comment: Did you configure your firewall to allow nfs ?

Comment: Yes, I can mount NFS exports on client but I wonder why I still need to use `rpcbind` with v4

Comment: NFSv4 doesn't require rpcbind. But there are clients and tools around which still depend on that information, for example 'showmount'. Additionally, Linux nfsd uses /proc/fs/nfsd/portlist file to communicate port number to rpcbind, and this file somehow depends on running rpcbind process.

Comment: I can verify this problem on Debian 7 with kernel 3.3.2 by adding `-N 2 -N 3` to `rpc.nfsd` in the start script and getting the same error "unable to set any sockets for nfsd"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a bug in NFS server kernel module. It was [patched](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7e55b59b2f32afc83452ae250dfd6173c9a7b515) in December 2013.

Starting with kernel 3.14, `rpcbind` is no longer required to run in-kernel NFS server.

(assuming that server is configured to use only NFSv4 and higher)

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/sunrpc/svc.c?v=3.14#L966

You can find more information about that change in this thread:

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-nfs/msg41053.html

Therefore, your configuration:

```
MOUNTD_NFS_V2="no"
MOUNTD_NFS_V3="no"
RPCNFSDARGS="-N 2 -N 3"
```

should now work without `rpcbind`.

When you use only NFSv4, none of these services are required:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/nfslock
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rpcgssd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rpcidmapd
/etc/rc.d/init.d/rpcsvcgssd
```

Comment: `rpc.idmapd` is only required for NFSv4. GSS is also required for Kerberos security. Though both are optional.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted documentation from RedHat was wrong and got fixed by [Bug 521215](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=521215): `rpc.mountd` still must be used to *setup* NFSv4, but strictly speaking it is not required to be running after that.

- `nfs`: **Server** for all versions of NFS: v2, v3, v4, v4.1
- `rpcbind`/`portmapper`: **Server**, strictly only for NFS <= v3. But also for NFS v4 as the Linux Kernel NFS server tries to register itself and fails to start if `rpcbind` is not running.
- `rpc.mountd`: **Server**, strictly only for NFS <=3. But also for NFS v4 as the Linux Kernel uses it to check, if the connecting client is allowed to connect.
- `nfslock`: **Server** only for NFS <= v3
- `rpc.idmapd`: Optional **Server** (and older **Clients**) for NFS v4
- `rpc.quotad`: **Server** for using disk quota
- `rpc.statd`: **Server** only for NFS <= v3

When using Kerberos (`sec=krb`/`krb5i`/`krb5p`) the following services are required:

- `rpc.gssd`: **Client**
- `rpc.svcgssd`: **Server**

Please note that even they carry `rpc.` in their name, they use the Linux kernel internal mechanism `rpc_pipef` for communication between the Linux kernel and the user space helper; so `rpcbind` AKA `portmapper` is not needed for them.

Answer (score -3):

Check rpcbind service. If it stopped working start and then try starting nfs service.

```
service rpcbind start
service nfs start
```

Comment: This answer is very low quality. OP has stated rpcbind was not required since nfsv4. The question has already been answered : it was a kernel bug.